# Why did Git just perform a forced update without the --force flag?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

We had a really bizarre incident at work yesterday. I performed some changes to a repository, committed, and invoked `git push`, just like I always do. Here's what happened:

```
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ git add file_a.h 
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ git add file_b.h
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ git add file_c
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ git add file_d.h
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ git commit
[master a9c4595] Perform change requested by customer.
 4 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ git push
Enumerating objects: 17, done.
Counting objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 845 bytes | 845.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git.corp.com:port/project/repo.git
 + 38a09ed...a9c4595 master -> master (forced update)
 + 38a09ed...a9c4595 38 -> 38 (forced update)
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ git log
```

Specifically observe that `(forced update)` notice there. My coworker had pushed changes to this repository just before me, and in my ~7 years of Git usage, every single time this scenario has happened, Git has warned me that the remote has changes I don't have, and asks me to pull before I push. **Why did this not happen now?** Git instead erased my coworker's commit on the remote, and replaced it with my own `HEAD^`. How would I go about preventing this in the future?

Additional details: Our Git workflow, in terms of integration with other projects, relies on tags, so we have a `post-commit` hook that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tag_ver="$(git describe --tags --match 0 | cut -d'-' -f2)"

git rev-list HEAD | head -n1 | xargs git tag $tag_ver
```

So every time a commit is made, it just increments the tag by one.

Comment: What does `git config remote.origin.push` print? Is it like `+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`?

Comment: @ElpieKay It prints `+refs/tags/*`

Comment: The leading `+` in the refspec means force-update. But in your case, it's for tags. Run `git config -l` and see if there  are any other refspecs with a leading `+` for branches. `remote.origin.fetch` can be ignored as it affects the fetch only.

Comment: @ElpieKay I might have just found the culprit. `git config -l` revealed the following line: `remote.origin.push=+refs/heads/*
`

Comment: @LeGEC The tags are automated, and they are always numeric. Though that doesn't stop someone from manually setting an invalid tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692107/why-did-git-just-perform-a-forced-update-without-the-force-flag#comment110870195_62692107):

> I might have just found the culprit. `git config -l` revealed the following line: `remote.origin.push=+refs/heads/*`

This is indeed the reason.  As [the `git push` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) says:

> When the command line does not specify what to push with `<refspec>...`
> arguments or `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` options, the command finds the
> default `<refspec>` by consulting `remote.*.push` configuration, and if it
> is not found, honors `push.default` configuration to decide what to push
> (See [git-config(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for the meaning of `push.default`).

A refspec that omits the colon, for `git push` purposes, effectively repeats the `<src>` part, so your `remote.origin.push` makes `git push origin` act like `git push origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`.  The leading `+` sign sets the force flag for this refspec.